# Binding memcached to storage underneath the same

Tags: memcached

Is there a way to bind memcached to local storage underneath it directly? Will explain with an example. Lets say hbase is used as as backend which is distributed. A layer of memcached is used as a caching layer and it can be considered to be a exact replica (in some sense) of hbase below it. Assuming there are 4 nodes in the system of which 3 are used for hbase and has a memcached layer on top of it and 1 node is used for compute. Usual norms is to lookup if memcached has some key. If it has, fetch it and use it for compute. If it doesn't have, load data from hbase and load it to the memcached server located on the same node where hbase had the data. Even though we try to exploit the data locality here, if there is cache miss, data travels from hbase to the compute node and then it reaches the memcached(and hence data locality goes in vain). So, is there a way to define a function and delegate it to memcached, which should be invoked on a cache miss. In the above context, it should load the data from local hbase rather than we loading the data to compute node and sending it to memcached.
In simple terms, get() should take in a custom method which would be invoked if the entry is not available in the remote memcached.

Answer (score 1):

That's not memcached's job, is built to be *clean* and *fast*. If you are worried about the 'traveling' of data, create a service/deamon on those nodes that get asked for the data when data isn't available in memcached & delivers it to both the requester & the local memcached deamon. So, get from memcached, failover to running service on hbase/memcached nodes.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to do something on similar lines @Wrikken. I am planning to tweak memcached source code itself to handle cache miss, rather than adding a new daemon to it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I was actually looking for something like a cacheloader given [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: Yes, which is something you'd either build or install. Don't try to hack it into memcached though IMHO. Memcached may be your cacheloader's volatile backend, but hacking in callbacks is creating an entirely different application. Let memcached do what it's good at, what fronts your memcached it up to you.

Comment: I do agree with you Wrikken. But I am really surprised that memcached doesn't provide one such funtionality. I do accept that its a in-memory caching layer. But the sole reason for going to in-memory caching is that reading from disc is expensive. Adding to it, reading from a remote disc is much more expensive right. Anyways, as you suggested I am not trying to tweak memcached. My code base is java and if I tweak memcached(which is in C), I have to have make native calls and not sure about the performance hit bcz of this.